# remove shadow from HorizontalBarChartView

Tags: ios-charts

My `HorizontalBarChartView` has a drop shadow. How can I remove it?

The chart is setup like this:

    `chartView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    chartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = NO;
    chartView.drawBarShadowEnabled = NO;
    chartView.drawBordersEnabled = NO;
    chartView.leftAxis.enabled = NO;
    chartView.rightAxis.enabled = NO;
    chartView.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = NO;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disable `BarChartView.drawBarShadowEnabled`

There is shadowColor in BarChartDataSet too:

```
/// the color used for drawing the bar-shadows. The bar shadows is a surface behind the bar that indicates the maximum value
public var barShadowColor = UIColor(red: 215.0/255.0, green: 215.0/255.0, blue: 215.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are using swift instead of objc, just replace 'NO' by 'false'

```
chartView.drawBarShadowEnabled = false
```

edit :
From the code source :

```
/// if set to true, a grey area is drawn behind each bar that indicates the maximum value
173     @objc open var drawBarShadowEnabled: Bool
```

in ChartsDemo example [link](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/8245f32498739cde83dc729123d58538184b78f5/ChartsDemo-OSX/PlaygroundChart.playground/Pages/BarChart.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift)

```
//: ### General
chartView.pinchZoomEnabled          = false
chartView.drawBarShadowEnabled      = false
chartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled    = false
chartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = true
chartView.fitBars                   = true
```

Comment: Please provide more explanation, from where you find the suggestion to provide false instead of no or documentation link etc.

Comment: It depends if you use swift or objc version of ios-charts (but it wasn't specified).